# Gazebo blank/black screen (not responding)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am a beginner at ROS and I tried today to run the gazebo for a start via ROS. I use ROS Jade.

I ran at the start :

```
roscore
```

then in a new terminal I ran :

```
 roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

The gazebo gui popped up and it shows black/blank screen with a Real Time Factor = 0.0 and it's stuck there no matter how much time I let it to load .
The same thing happens when I just run the command :

```
gazebo
```

with the exception that then the gui pops a "Does not respond" message .Does this mean that my pc requirements doesn't meet the requirements to run gazebo ?

I am at ubuntu 14.04 LTS (dual installed with Windows) and with the following system overview :

```
Memory :     3,7 GiB
Processor :  Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 530 @ 2.93GHz × 4 
Graphics :   Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.0)
OS type :    64-bit
Disk :       16,2 GB
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233239/gazebo-blank/black-screen-(not-responding)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will close this question, because after I changed pc to work with ROS and Gazebo I don't have this problem anymore.

Probably the reason why I met this issue with my desktop pc is because of the low capabilities of my graphics card (ATI Radeon HD 5450).

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0